# Magento 2: How to create popup alert in magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax, jquery

I added a button in block which hits custom controller (I am not using any template)

This is controller code:

```
<?php
namespace Vtn\UnexportedOrder\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 

class Export extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Vtn_UnexportedOrder::export';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_pageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface $orderRepo,
       \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
       \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->orderRepo = $orderRepo;
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $itemId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('itemid');
        $item = $this->orderRepo->get($itemId);

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('itemid')):
            $itemId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('itemid');
            $item = $this->orderRepo->get($itemId);
            $data = $item->getName()." is already exported";
            $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
            $resultJson->setData($data);
            return $resultJson;
        endif;
    }
}
```

For now it displays products name on controller url (frontname/controller/export).
But I want to display it on same controller where button exists using ajax call and display this product name in popup on this controller url (frontname/controller/view)

Comment: So, do you already have a template, where the button is integrated (basically a phtml file, where the button gets inserted)?

Comment: Actually I am using any template I just add button dynamically from block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a phtml file inside your static cms-block:

```
{{block class="<vendor_name>\<module_name>\Block\<module_name>" name="<your_block_name>" template="<vendor_name>_<module_name>::<template_directory>/filename.phtml"}}
```

Inside of the phtml-file, you can add javascript and the logic to call your script via ajax:

```
<button data-trigger="openmymodal">Click me!</button>
<div id="your-modal-div"></div>
    <script>
      require(
               [
                   'jquery',
                   'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
               ],
               function (
                   $,
                   modal
               ) {
    
                     var modaloption = {
                       type: 'popup',
                       modalClass: 'modal-popup',
                       responsive: true,
                       innerScroll: true,
                       clickableOverlay: true,
                       title: $.mage.__('Popup-Title'),
                       buttons: [{
                          text: $.mage.__('Close'),
                          class: '',
                          click: function () {
                              this.closeModal();
                          }
                      }],
                      trigger: '[data-trigger=openmymodal]'
                   };
                      var modelcreate = modal(modaloption, $('#your-modal-div'));
                      var sku="123";
    
                   $.ajax({
                      method: "POST",
                      url: "/frontname/controller/export",
                      data: { itemid: sku},
                      dataType: "json",
                      async: true,
                      success : function(response){                    
                        console.log(response);
                        $('#your-modal-div').append(response);

                    
                      }
                    });
               });
    </script>
```